# Mysql cannot add or update child row, Foreign key related failure

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-key-relationship

> Error: cannot add or update a child row: foreign key constraint fails

Following is the code that is creating the error:

```
ALTER TABLE 'catalog_eav_attribute' 
  ADD CONSTRAINT 'FK_CATALOG_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ID' 
  FOREIGN KEY ('attribute_id') REFERENCES 'eav_attribute' ('attribute_id)' 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I uploaded the Structure of SQL and its has no issue , but when i insert the data i am getting the above related error. I read somewhere and i predict its because of lousy data.What are the other possibilities for the error ? Any suggestions or solution  will be great.

Comment: This is not valid MySQL. Identifiers are quoted with backticks, not single quotes.  This wouldn't even run.

Comment: What are you inserting? And does the `attribute_id` field reference something in the `eav_attribute` table?

Comment: @Michael, I use both single quotes and backticks with MySQL successfully.

Comment: @SableFoste In ANSI_QUOTES mode you can double quote identifiers, you cannot single quote them. Single quotes are for string literals. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: @Michael:  Wow, good to know, but a little scary... I might have a lot of code to go back and update, just in case... Thank you for the info.

Comment: Run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS query. It might shed light on the problem.

Comment: i was trying to migrate the magento system  from one server to another , i disabled and enabled the the foreign key feature in sql file , once i included that code in start and end of the file , it stopped giving me error. Thanks guys and sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

"For storage engines other than InnoDB, MySQL Server parses the FOREIGN KEY syntax in CREATE TABLE statements, but does not use or store it."

From:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html

I'm not sure, but if your table is MyISAM and not InnoDB, your syntax might not work.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means whatever number you're trying to put into the attribute_id column doesn't yet exist in the eav_attribute.attribute_id column.

Can you insert a value that *does* already exist in eav_attribute.attribute_id? (You probably can.)

Can you provoke the same error by trying to insert a value that *doesn't* exist in eav_attribute.attribute_id?

Reconcile the differences, and you're done. You need to determine which attribute ids don't exist in eav_attribute.attribute_id, and fix that.